# Find the frequency distribution of the first character of the name in the table in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a table like

```
key Name
 1   snake
 2   panda
 3   parrot
 4   catipie
 5   cattie
```

Now I want to find the count of occurrence of first character of each row and sort in descending order and if there is a tie , it should sort in lexical order , so my output looks like :

```
c 2
p 2
s 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Select first value by indexing `str[0]` and count by [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
s = df['Name'].str[0].value_counts()
print (s)
p    2
c    2
s    1
Name: Name, dtype: int64
```

And for `DataFrame` add [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df['Name'].str[0].value_counts().rename_axis('first').reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
  first  count
0     p      2
1     c      2
2     s      1
```

If necessary sorting same count by letters add [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['first','count'], ascending=[True, False])
print (df)
  first  count
1     c      2
0     p      2
2     s      1
```

And for Series:

```
s = df.set_index('first')['count']
print (s)
first
c    2
p    2
s    1
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

Last use [`to_string`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_string.html):

```
print (s.to_string(header=None))
c    2
p    2
s    1
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, this gives me an idea. I want to output this as a series without any column names and it should be sorted on descending count and ascending on lexical if there is a tie

Comment: p in panda , p in parrot , p in catipie, makes it 3

Comment: thank you :) but its failing on my test set. Can you please check

Comment: @Mighty - what test?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183641/discussion-between-mighty-and-jezrael).